# Is there any tool to pretty print DOM tree with whitespace text node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My question is seeking for some existing tools or solutions.
How to pretty print DOM tree with whitespace text node like the picture demonstrates?
[image: DOM visualized]

The picture is from here [MDN guides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace). Really appreciate it if you know productivity tools like this.

Thanks! I just don't bother to write js code traversing the whole thing and think there should be tools for it already, but I really can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is tools like this.

But if you just want to see the DOM tree, Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera have an explorer in their [development tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

You can also open the console and type `document.documentElement` to see the root element. Then you can navigate on every children of your webpage.

Comment: Yes I tried this, but just want some shortcutting tools.